# Rounding down to the closest multiple

Tags: javascript, game-engine

I have a tile system where each tile is 32x32 pixels. I'm trying to make a function where the type of tile is returned based on the x y coordinate parameters, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to properly convert the xy coordinates into the 32x32 grid system I have.

```
function getTileAtCoordinates(x, y) {
    if (x < 32) x = 32;
    if (y < 32) y = 32;
    xTile = x;
    xTile = xTile - (x % 32);
    xTile = x / 32;

    yTile = y;
    yTile = yTile - (x % 32);
    yTile = y / 32;


    return getMapTile(xTile, yTile);

}
```

The getMapTile function obviously getting the tile type from 2 dimensional array (x and y). For some reason the function is occasionally trying to use decimal values, which if my math is right shouldn't happen - as decimal values are never passed to the function.

edit: What I'm basically trying to accomplish is if the coordinates are (32, 32) then that translates to (1, 1), and (65, 33) would translate to (3, 2).

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: If the integer part of the decimal value is right, you might just explicitly convert it to an integer and not worry about it...

Comment: @David I'm calling the function with the x and y coordinates of the player, which would both be positive integers.

Comment: getMapTile just returns my mapArray[x][y], so the second tile across top row would be x=1 y=0

Answer (score 0):

```
function getTileAtCoordinates(x, y) {
  return getMapTile(Math.ceil(x/32), Math.ceil(y/32))
}
```

This is assuming your tile x and y start with 1, not with 0. Only coordinates 0 return tile 0.

It can be adapted to work at 0-31, 32-63, etc

```
function getTileAtCoordinates(x, y) {
  return getMapTile(Math.floor((x+1)/32), Math.floor((y+1)/32))
}
```

Which would return tiles 0 for coord 0-31, tile 1 for 32-63, etc.

Or, if your coordinates start at 1 (1-32, 33-64, 65-96 etc), but your tiles start at 0

```
function getTileAtCoordinates(x, y) {
  return getMapTile(Math.floor((x-1)/32), Math.floor((y-1)/32))
}
```